# Handling file upload API in WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

- I am a beginner in WebFlux. My use case is to develop an API handling csv, xls, xlsx files. I am trying to use more of reactive programming.
- For parsing csv, xls, xlsx file, I could not find direct support for reactive programming. So I am using libraries OpenCSV, POI and using `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` to not impact the non-blocking processing as suggested in this [article](https://medium.com/@victortemitope95/how-to-write-and-download-a-csv-file-in-spring-webflux-5df8d817a597).
- I also saw in this [article](https://medium.com/@eaimanshoshi/step-by-step-procedure-of-spring-webflux-multipart-file-upload-and-read-each-line-without-saving-it-6a12be64f6ee) that the input file to the controller is of format `FilePart` but libraries OpenCSV, POI expect the input in BufferedReader, FileInputStream, etc. formats. Could someone please help to understand how this can be handled?